# Firebase Cloud Function running WebAssembly module

Tags: google-cloud-functions, webassembly

I know we have Node.js 8 and soon version 10, and both can run WebAssembly code. It will probably make cold start faster.

Can I run WebAssembly modules inside Cloud Function?

Comment: For the purpose of posting to Stack Overflow, it would be best if you actually try it yourself first, the post with the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

A webassembly loader is implemented as an npm package [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasm).You can specify in the package.json all your npm package dependencies for the cloud function module [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/helloworld).

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on which cloud platform you are asking about, at the moment the only one that I know of that supports it is Cloudflare Workers.

Even when other cloud providers begin to support wasm, it won't solve the cold start delay, vendors rotate which functions are in memory ready to be executed based on when they were last called in most cases.

Writing parts of your Node scripts in a language like C or Rust that compiles to wasm may very well decrease the overall runtime. But it won't change the fact that if you're function isn't being called regularly enough providers will reallocate resources to functions that are.